# Python - Game of Life with functions issue

Tags: python, function, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Have seen many different ways to do the **game of life** rules in python. I am new and trying to use numpy and functions - see below.
I tested the *cal_live* function by itself with individual elements in the array, and the sum is calculating correctly. However, it doesn't give correct output when implement with *evolve* function. Anyone please help?
Note: test with this list and it fails.
test_case_2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],]

```
def cal_live(r, c, arr):
    """
    Calculate the number of live neighbors.
    
    Parameters:
    r -- element's row index
    c -- element's column index
    """
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(max(0,r - 1), min(arr.shape[0]-1, r + 2)):
    # if (i >= 0) and (i < arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(max(0, c - 1), min(arr.shape[1]-1, c + 2)):
        # if (j >= 0) and (j < arr.shape[1]):
            count += arr[i][j]
    
    return count - arr[r][c]

def evolve(initial_state):
    # live case
    arr = np.array(initial_state)
    
    for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(arr):
        row, col = idx
        live_neighbor_count = cal_live(row, col, arr)
        
        if live_neighbor_count == 3:
            arr[idx] = 1
        elif live_neighbor_count == 2 and x == 1:
            arr[idx] = 1
        else:
            arr[idx] = 0
    
    return arr.tolist()
```

Comment: `evolve()` calls `cal_livechance()`, not `cal_live()`.

Comment: sorry my bad. Just edited it. Had multiple versions earlier and wanted to make the function name more condense.

Comment: I'm not good with `numpy`, but are you updating the same array that you're writing to? You can't do that without clever workwarounds. You need to read from one array, and write to another array. If you write to the same array you're reading from, you'll change how many neighbors cells have before you've checked how many neighbors they have.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, you are right. Created another array to store the new value and it works! You guys are awesome!

Comment: That's probably the most common thing people overlook when implementing Life. As a tip, the way I've handled it historically is to create two identical arrays at the very start, and designate one the "write" array, and one the "read" array. At the end of each generation, just swap them. The other way is to have one array, but each element is a bitfield of two bits, where one is the "read" bit and one is the "write" bit. That can save memory, but is much harder to impalement.

Comment: totally agree. these are the subtle but important things that newbies like me would not notice until actually implementing it. I got the first part about creating 2 identical arrays the do read/write. Not sure how to do the second method...

Comment: @moonH Don't worry about the second way. If you've never dealt with bitfields before, that solution will have a steeper learning curve. I only mentioned it because I had actually read about that implementation like a week before and thought it was a cool idea to save memory. In your case, saving memory will likely be the least of your concerns.